# kineticjs with globalCompositeOperation

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, globalcompositeoperation

I want to make a program works like photoshop.
So I tried to modify the ***globalCompositeOperation*** to simulate the layer blending property

However, ***Kinetic.Context*** does not pass the ***globalCompositeOperation*** property to real ***contetx2d***.

After trace the code http://pastebin.com/4neU7VF8 (link to modified kineticJs also included)

I modify the ***Kinetic.Context*** to allow such action.

And modify ***Kinetic.Node*** to make it remember what ***globalCompositeOperation*** it was settled.

And modify ***kinetic.Container.prototype._drawChildren*** to make it switch ***globalCompositeOperation*** of context automatically base on what ***globalCompositeOperation***  its child nodes desire.

After done that.
it actually works in plain container such as a ***Kinetic.Layer*** contains several ***Kinetic.Shape***

however it seems doesn't work in nested containers, 
such as a ***stage*** contains two layer
and the top layer has the ***globalCompositeOperation*** attribute
just like the layer contains red line in this http://jsbin.com/tumef/16/

Does anyone has idea, what did I miss?

Comment: To clarify your question: In your example I see drag-creating a red line will 'erase' the content across all layers using destination-out compositing. What is your desired result?

Comment: the red line draw on the top layer, but the top layer has settled to "destination-out", so the top layer should be invisible and use that red line to crop out the bottom layer and its contents instead of just show it there. The line erase the bottom layer after you release your mouse is actually append into the bottom layer and works as intended